# Finding attribute by attribute value with Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<Services total="3">
    <link href="http://localhost/service1" rel="s1"/>
    <link href="http://localhost/service2" rel="s2"/>
    <link href="http://localhost/service3" rel="s3"/>
</Services>
```

Using Python I want to look up the `href` attribute of `rel="s2"`. This is my current code:

```
doc = ER.fromstring(xml)
href = doc.find(".//link[@rel='s2']").attrib['href']
println(href)
```

However this only gives me:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: your code works for me (except `println`). `NoneType` means `find()` couldn't find element - maybe you used different path or different xml.

Comment: Works for me too. Are you sure it's the whole XML data?

Comment: D**n, I copied the wrong snippets. The XML includes namespaces which need to be taken into account when applying the XPath. It works this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in xml path. try following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ER

doc = ER.fromstring(xml)
href = doc.find(".//link/.[@rel='s2']")
print(href)
```